# Latin characters in AWK

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a question about Latin-1 characters in AWK, for example ï (an i with two dots above (239)).

When I replace ï with i in a string created in AWK (I replace the two dots by one), it works:

```
A="Aïda"
A=gensub("ï","i","g",A)
```

But when I do,

```
awk '
{
    $0=gensub("ï","i","g",$0)
}' \  
<(cat units.csv)
```

where the string "Aïda" is in the file units.csv, the ï is not substituted, so apparently it is not in AWK. This is what I don't understand. I also don't know how to see what is is AWK instead of ï.

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- awk won't write change back to your original file (input), you have to output to a tmp file, in your awk script, you didn't output anything
- the cat part is not needed just `awk '..' file`
- `gensub` is not necessary in this case, `gsub` may work for your requirement. but both work fine

see example:

```
kent$  cat file
ï ï ï ï ï

kent$  awk '{$0=gensub("ï","x","g")}1' file  # (or awk '{print gensub("ï","x","g")}' file)
x x x x x

kent$  awk 'gsub("ï","x")' file                                                                                                                                             
x x x x x
```

Comment: Except that the newest gawk (4.1) can support inplace file modification ( http://lwn.net/Articles/550212/ )

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai thx for the info. I am using archlinux. and just checked, the 4.1 not yet in arch's repo....  would like to try new feature when it comes.

Comment: Thanks. But with the GNU Awk 4.0.1 the latin char ï (239) is not replaced with x.

Comment: I tested with gawk 4.0.2, but I think 401 should work too. your terminal setting problem?

Comment: Thanks, I must apologize. When I exported my Excel spreadsheet, apparently I didn't save it to utf-8. So there was 239 in the file and not 303 257. But then I have another question. So I have the (wrong) string Aïda where the second byte is 239. How can one test this in AWK, so take one or more bytes from a string, and test it against one or more numbers?